# Why multiplying int and char doesn't produce overflow in c?

Tags: c

I have this code here where i multiply char type and int type variables and store them in different int variables

```
int m,n;
int num = 1000;
char c = 50;
m = num*c*c;
n = c*c*num;

printf("%d\n", m);
printf("%d\n", n);
```

and it outputs

```
2500000
2500000
```

I expected the output values to overflow, but it outputed the correct result.Why didn't it overflow?

Comment: the values are implicitly converted to int. `c * c` is internally executed with all ints as `(int)c * (int)c`

Comment: There is a quite lot written here about [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). There a several similar questions to be [found](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c+stackoverflow+integer+promotion+site:stackoverflow.com) too.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know it doesn't overload? You just assume subject to the output.

If your `int` is 2 bytes, it overflows. Otherwise, in the case of higher bytes, not.

However, we don't know what architecture you are working on.

For example, if the code runs by [`clang x86-64` compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/GOpIf8), it yields as follows.

```
    // byte 8 bits, int(dword) 32 bits
    mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 12]
    movsx   ecx, byte ptr [rbp - 13]
    imul    eax, ecx
    movsx   ecx, byte ptr [rbp - 13]
    imul    eax, ecx
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], eax
```

As can be seen, the result is preserved in a field whose type is `dword`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains two separate questions:

- What about multiplying integer and char types?
- What about the maximum value of integer types?

The first question is answered in the comments from @pmg and @Weather Vane.

The second question can be answered by your own compiler, you just verify the value of `INT_MAX`, this is the maximum value an integer might have according to your compiler.

Comment: Yes, @EricPostpischil, you're right of course.  Clearly I needed to have consumed more coffee before writing what I did.  But the point is still that the maximum representable value for an `int` in most modern implementations is more than sufficient for the values the OP is asking about.